# Is it possible to use XamlReader from a XAML file to load in a block of XAML text?

Tags: wpf, xaml, xamlreader

I use the following DataTemplate in **many** controls:

```
<pages:BasePageManageItems x:Class="TestApp.Pages.PageManageAddresses"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"  
    xmlns:pages="clr-namespace:TestHistorierung.Pages"
    xmlns:tk="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wpf/2008/toolkit"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             Background="#eee"
             VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
    <pages:BasePageManageItems.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="manageAreaCellTemplate">
            <Border Padding="2">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Style="{DynamicResource ManageLinkStyle}"
                    Tag="{Binding Id}" Text="Delete" MouseDown="System_Delete_Click"
                    Margin="0 0 5 0"/>
                    <TextBlock Style="{DynamicResource ManageLinkStyle}"
                   Tag="{Binding Id}" Text="Edit" MouseDown="System_Edit_Click"
                    Margin="0 0 5 0"/>
                    <TextBlock Style="{DynamicResource ManageLinkStyle}"
                   Tag="{Binding Id}" Text="Add" MouseDown="System_Add_Click"
                    Margin="0 0 5 0"/>
                    <TextBlock Style="{DynamicResource ManageLinkStyle}"
                   Tag="{Binding Id}" Text="Copy" MouseDown="System_Copy_Click"
                    Margin="0 0 5 0"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </pages:BasePageManageItems.Resources>
```

**Is there any way to use XamlReader from XAML so that I can simply load the *text* of the DataTemplate into the XAML file dynamically?** I'm imagining something like this (pseudo code):

```
<pages:BasePageManageItems x:Class="TestApp.Pages.PageManageAddresses"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"  
    xmlns:pages="clr-namespace:TestHistorierung.Pages"
    xmlns:tk="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wpf/2008/toolkit"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             Background="#eee"
             VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
    <pages:BasePageManageItems.Resources>
        <XamlReader Load="XamlBlocks/DateTemplateManageButtons.xaml"/>
    </pages:BasePageManageItems.Resources>
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't place the XamlReader tag in Xaml (I don't even know if it's possible). Instead you can use XamlReader class to create compiled Xaml in code, and attach it to parent element:

```
 var element = XamlReader.Load(stringContainingXaml);
 this.somePanel.Children.Insert(0, element as FrameworkElement);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can put the common XAML in a ResourceDictionary:

XamlBlocks/DateTemplateManageButtons.xaml (added to the project, build action = Page)

```
<ResourceDictionary x:Class="myNmaespace.DateTemplateManageButtons"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
     <DataTemplate x:Key="manageAreaCellTemplate">
            <Border Padding="2">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Style="{DynamicResource ManageLinkStyle}"
                    Tag="{Binding Id}" Text="Delete" MouseDown="System_Delete_Click"
                    Margin="0 0 5 0"/>
                    <TextBlock Style="{DynamicResource ManageLinkStyle}"
                   Tag="{Binding Id}" Text="Edit" MouseDown="System_Edit_Click"
                    Margin="0 0 5 0"/>
                    <TextBlock Style="{DynamicResource ManageLinkStyle}"
                   Tag="{Binding Id}" Text="Add" MouseDown="System_Add_Click"
                    Margin="0 0 5 0"/>
                    <TextBlock Style="{DynamicResource ManageLinkStyle}"
                   Tag="{Binding Id}" Text="Copy" MouseDown="System_Copy_Click"
                    Margin="0 0 5 0"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ResourceDictionary>
```

XamlBlocks/DateTemplateManageButtons.xaml.cs :

```
namespace myNamespace
{
    public partial class DateTemplateManageButtons : ResourceDictionary
    {
        private void System_Delete_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            // event handler code
        }
        // other event handlers
    }
}
```

And in your page:

```
<pages:BasePageManageItems x:Class="TestApp.Pages.PageManageAddresses"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"  
    xmlns:pages="clr-namespace:TestHistorierung.Pages"
    xmlns:tk="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wpf/2008/toolkit"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             Background="#eee"
             VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
    <pages:BasePageManageItems.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="XamlBlocks/DateTemplateManageButtons.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </pages:BasePageManageItems.Resources>
```

If you need the event handler code to run in the page and not the resource dictionary you can do something like:

Define interface for the events:

```
public interface IDateTemplateManageButtonsEvents 
{
    void System_Delete_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e); 
}
```

Implement that interface in all pages that use the data template

In the resource dictionary cs file:

```
private IDateTemplateManageButtonsEvents FindPage(object sender)
{
    DependencyObject current = sender as DependencyObject;
    while(current != null && !(current is IDateTemplateManageButtonsEvents))
    {
        current = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(current);
    }
    return (IDateTemplateManageButtonsEvents)current;
}
private void System_Delete_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    FindPage(sender).System_Delete_Click(sender, e);
}
```

Comment: When I do this it tells me: "'ResourceDictionary' root element requires a x:Class attribute to support event handlers in the XAML file. Either remove the event handler for the MouseDown event, or add a x:Class attribute to the root element." when I add the x:Class attribute, I get errors like this: "Missing partial modifier on declaration of type 'TestApp.Pages.BasePageManageItems'; another partial declaration of this type exists"

Comment: oops, didn't notice the event handlers, I updated the answer - this makes the ResourceDictionary-based solution a little more complex but rules out XamlReader-based solution completely (the event wiring is done by the compiler with generated code, XamlReder can't handle events).